# Ceiling light fixture held up only by the pressure of two screws?

Tags: lighting

I have a light fixture, pictured, whose cap (bottom white part) is a glass cap that is apparently just held in place with two screws that don't have a head (slot). The screw goes through the metal casing but there aren't any holes for the screws to go in in the glass thing. It seems to be holding, but is that normal...?

[image: ceiling fixture]

Comment: Normal, and allows for a wide variety of globes ot be used, so if you don't like your globe, change it.  The key is **don't crank the screw down hard**.  The purpose is to capture the lip, not clamp it.   Finger tight is plenty.

Comment: This is a good example of something designed so it is only easy to see the right way to take it apart, *after* you have taken it apart ;)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is very normal thing. The end of the thumb screw engages a lip on the glass cover or globe. It is more common that there are three such screws. Here is a side view cross section to show approximately what it looks like.

[image]

To remove the globe or glass cover you simply use the thumb head to back out the screws till the lip on the glass part can drop down.

Note that on some fixtures there may even be only one thumb screw with one or two fixed pins or ledges on the metal fixture on the far side. This type you back out the thumb screw and then have to tip down the globe till it disengages from the fixed points on the other side.